# Angularjs difference between fetched and locally modified data

Tags: angularjs

I fetch data from an API and it gives my something like this:

```
{id: 1, name: ''}
```

The field name is `ng-model` for an input field.
As soon as I write something in the field, the json object I have a reference to, will have name equals to something else than empty.
That's normal behaviour.

However, if Im interested in knowing if name "was" empty when I fetched data, can I do this in a simple way? Without needing to create new variables?

Basically I want to have 2 `ng-if` elements and only display one of them. But I cannot trust the data in the object because I don't know if the name-field has been changed locally or on the server:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name" ng-if="ctrl.name === ''" />
<span ng-if="ctrl.name !== ''">{{ctrl.name}}</span>
```

Comment: Use a boolean variable to separate the 2 cases, if possible. If not show us the controller code to understand how it works

Answer (score 1):

Use can the [`$dirty`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$dirty) (this docs are about `form` but it's true for `input`s as well) prop of an input in `form` so the logic will be: show the input if the `name` is not defined (`undefined` or an empty string) **or** when the input is dirty - means the user typed in the input. And the opposite for the `span`. This way you'll not have to hold another param.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', function() {
  // comment this line to simulate name was empty
  // this.name = 'text from server';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="ctrl.name"
           ng-if="!ctrl.name || myForm.name.$dirty" />
    <span ng-if="!!ctrl.name && !myForm.name.$dirty">{{ctrl.name}}</span>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```